# AS3, Flash - Track Page?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Is it possible somehow to check what page this Flash is viewed on?

Like to see if my flash game is played from Facebook, Kongregate or trought my own site?

Comment: Please see the new answer provided, I had wrongly just assumed Flex since that's where my knowledge base was built up (never really used Flash IDE much as I can't stand the code editor, and my job required a deep understanding of Flex so never had time to fiddle with Flash IDE by itself much).  The call to ExternalInterface he's using will invoke the javascript in the parameter of the call method which will return the URL (the only place this wouldn't work is if Javascript is disabled in the browser from what I can tell).

Answer (score 1):

Try calling Javascript via the `ExternalInterface` class:

```
var url:String = ExternalInterface.call('window.location.href.toString');
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. When I put this into the actions, it shows me this in the log: `Error: Error #2067: The ExternalInterface is not available in this container. ExternalInterface requires Internet Explorer ActiveX, Firefox, Mozilla 1.7.5 and greater, or other browsers that support NPRuntime.
 at Error$/throwError()
 at flash.external::ExternalInterface$/call()
 at main_fla::MainTimeline/frame1()[main_fla.MainTimeline::frame1:1]
Cannot display source code at this location.`

Comment: ^^ That might be because I am doing it directly from Flash. Right.. then this function doesn't work.. Right?

Comment: Yup.  Doing it right from flash you don't have a URL anyway...  You may want to check that ExternalInterface is available before you make the call. Also, I think that window.location.href may not work on old IE, a quick web search could tell you the best cross browser way to get the url with JavaScript

Comment: Okay. Thanks. So what will the variable URL be? if like I am loading it from "http://localhost:8080/Flash%20Game%202/main.swf" or maybe "http://www.apps.facebook.com/something-random"? In this way I can test if it works.

Comment: it will be URL of the containing page or iframe.  So something like `localhost:8080/FlashGame/index.html`

Comment: Btw. How can I check that ExternalInterface is available before I make the Javascritp call?

Comment: Well.. If this is the right way to handle it: `if (ExternalInterface.isAvailable) {}` the it doesn't work. Says that isAvailable is an undefined property.

Comment: just looked it up,  it's just `ExternalInterface.available`  http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html

Comment: If this answer most helped you solve your problem, please accept it, if not please explain what the solution was (for future visitors with similar issue)